# Sanity check for obvious off-topic question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions

I came across the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/13420353/2310866 a while ago and since it is - at least in my opinion - obviously off-topic I voted to close it. But it has been 3 weeks now and the question still isn't closed.

I know that close votes go away after 4 days if the close threshold is not reached and since there is no number next to the close button that seems to be what has happened. But since I already voted to close this question I now cannot vote again.

So please can we make this question go away? I don't think there is any need for it to continue to stick around.

Comment: In the future, you can also ask in the tavern: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-free-snacks :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET got it :)

Comment: You can always drop a cv-pls in the [SO Close vote reviewers room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and if we see fit we are happy to help close such outliers.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå we closed that one with some help of the chatroom...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The majority of views on that question must have come from Google searches. It's so wildly off-topic that it wasn't getting enough views from people with vote-to-close privileges. I shut it down. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It is closed, could use a few more delete votes though imo :)

Comment: @TravisJ That didn't take long. I'm usually reluctant to break Google searches, but I found the "press F8" answer in a few other spots on the web, so nothing lost.

Comment: Yeah, I get the google search thing in general, but this specific question had so many things going against it that it seemed to just be asking for deletion :) For example, broken windows, SO is the wrong place for asking about using interfaces, pressing F8 is such a simple answer, no hand drawn circles, no waffles, no unicorns.